# DATABASE SYSTEM VERSION: The database server version 5.6.41-84.1 is less than the minimum required version 5.7.8

Tags: 9

I am trying to run a Drupal Security Update, update.php, but receive an error like this:

DATABASE SYSTEM VERSION
5.6.41-84.1
The database server version 5.6.41-84.1 is less than the minimum required version 5.7.8. (See Screenshot)

[image: Drupal Error]

My Drupal site version is 9.0.2.

Can anyone help me with this error?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your mySQL is out of date.  Drupal 9 requires at least 5.7.8, as described in the [Drupal database system requirements](https://www.drupal.org/docs/system-requirements/database-server-requirements).

This is not a Drupal problem *per se*; you will need to update the version of MySQL you are using on your web host.